# App force closes when plugged in after device reboot

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

I have a broadcast receiver that has the intent filter: ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED. The receiver is supposed to start a service. The receiver works great when the device has not been restarted, but once I restart the device and plug the device in, the app force closes. In my receiver I'm referencing another activity's static variable. Why does the app force close like that?

"dataSaved" is a SharedPreferences variable in MainActivity

```
if (MainActivity.dataSaved.getBoolean("User", false)) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, BatteryService.class)
    context.startService(i);
}
```

Comment: What does the stack backtrace tell you?

Comment: @AlanStokes It doesn't tell me anything. Once my device reboots, I connect my cable but before my system recognizes that I plugged the device in, my app force closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the `dataSaved` is a static `SharedPreference`, it is not initialized, so `getBoolean` throws a `NullPointerException`. You initialized it when somewhere in the `MainActivity` but after restart no `MainActivity` to initialize it

Get the sharedprefernce in the reciever

```
SharedPreferences dataSaved = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 boolean isUser = dataSaved.getBoolean("User", false);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on how to get the sharedpreference in the receiver? I've tried many different things such as using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream instead of sharedpreferences and still the same problem.